# How to get around your host having the mySQL database on a strange timezone

Tags: php, mysql, hosting, timezone-offset

I'm struggling with an inept hosting company who have taken over my previous hosting company. Apart from everything else they broke in the migration, the mySQL database is set to Australian time (unsure which city). I can set the PHP environment timezone by adding a php.ini file, but that still leaves the database in an odd state.

I think logically a host's database should be on UTC, and they should install the mysql timezone tables (but alas no, this will take weeks of badgering their "help"desk to get anywhere). I do not have permission to set any of the SQL variables of course (and without the timezone tables it will all be for nothing).

Now, I could get around this with an offset - I know the host is on +10hours, I need +12 hours, BUT this will all go wrong with daylight savings time (the australian one and my local one will not change at the same time).

And I run a booking system, so letting users book things 1 hour in the past will not go well...

So - as I have the PHP environment working, my solution is to get the offset from the PHP environment

```
$d = new DateTime();
echo $d->format('Z');
```

This gives me the offset in seconds -- divide this by 60*60 and we get the current current offset for my timezone. I *believe* this will change with daylight savings.

```
so I get an offset of +12 hours
```

Now I can apply this in the SQL, as the UTC_timestamp() function works, I can do

```
select CONVERT_TZ (UTC_TIMESTAMP, '+0:00', '+12:00');
```

to get the current date and time.

Should it be this hard to work around inept hosting companies? Is there an easier way??

Comment: Changing host isn't an option?

Comment: Set the timezone for the session every time you connect to the database?

Comment: Changing host - i'm already paid up for the next 8 months (so might as well take this opportunity to make my code more bullet proof). And re setting the timezone for the session each time - you cannot set the timezone to a name  e.g. Pacific/Auckland as the host hasn't loaded the mysql timezone functions, I think I could set it to +12 or +13 hours - having first worked out the actual timezone as above, but i unsure if i can do this - as it would have to be +12 relative to UTC not relative to the database time....